# How to get Contact form 7 Data with Keywords and Search Engine details By Google Analytics or Piwik

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, matomo, contact-form-7

I am looking for a solution to get an instant mail containing data of user filled on Contact form 7 and referral data by which user has been redirected from search engine to my form.

**Let me explain this in detail.**

I have a form on my wordpress website build by contact form 7, I am getting the data of form by email but I want the form data merged with analytics data showing details of **Keyword searched** by user to reach my form and fill it.

I have tried filters on google analytics but not getting my desired details.

Then did some research and find that google does not allow tracking personal details then I also Installed Piwik on my server but getting "*Keyword not defined*".

I only need data of users who have filled the form.

I am using google analytics and Piwik both and I am ready to use anything that can full fill my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting "Keyword not defined" in Piwik the user came from Google and was signed in. In this case, you will not get Keyword from Google search. The same will apply to Google Analytics. You are a victim of "not Provided", a change Google made a couple of years ago. http://analytics.blogspot.ca/2011/10/making-search-more-secure-accessing.html